# Oracle SQL: Update a record attribute with an *implicit* cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, sql-update

Part of my program creates a new record for the table qgame_history.This table has an id and a result field. The latest record will have a result which is null.
I want to use an implicit cursor to change this to a number like 1.
the id has datatype NUMBER(5,0) and the result has datatype NUMBER(1,0). I used the following code which has no errors but there is no change. any reason why?

since the null will be in the last record, this will be in the record with the highest id, hence the max(history_id).

```
set serveroutput on


DECLARE
cnumber qgame_history.history_id%TYPE;

CURSOR c1
   IS
     SELECT history_id INTO cnumber
     FROM qgame_history
     WHERE history_id = (SELECT MAX(history_id)
                        FROM
                        qgame_history);

BEGIN

      UPDATE qgame_history
        SET result = 1
        WHERE history_id = cnumber;

      COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I want to use this part of my project to demonstrate using implicit cursors.

Answer (score 1):

No need of cursor, you can do it in a single query like

```
  UPDATE qgame_history
    SET result = 1
    WHERE history_id = (SELECT MAX(history_id) FROM qgame_history);
```

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate being able to use an implicit cursor